# Modify query to only return users who joined in certain YEAR

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am doing an excercise for college and any time I enter further than is already here, from a previous query the red x with the explanation is disallowing me to continue

the question is

*Modify query so it only returns users who joined in 2020. List users by the date they joined.*

code I tried is :

```
SELECT sname, fname, username, 

cast(datejoined as date) as datejoined from user

Order by sname, datejoined;
```

I think I must change the whole date to just year but dont know how to do so - does anyone have any suggestions??  Thanks!

Comment: You at least need to use a `WHERE` clause. You'll find useful information in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can in MySQL use `HAVING` with the `YEAR` of your date column.

but why have you to cast it as DATE, save it as Date or datetime and you can use the column without cast it

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user(sname varchar(50),fname varchar(50),username varchar(50),datejoined varchar(19))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user VALUEs ('a','b','c','2021-01-01'),('a1','b1','c1','2020-01-01')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT sname, fname, username,
>
> cast(datejoined as date) as datejoined from user
> HAVING YEAR(datejoined) = 2021
> Order by sname, datejoined;
> ```
>
> ```
> sname | fname | username | datejoined
> :---- | :---- | :------- | :---------
> a     | b     | c        | 2021-01-01
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a44ff1407b6f4adb95c708a086d55c4)*